# How to render a bitmap image in Factor?

Tags: image, factor-lang

In a Factor program I want to:

1. programmatically draw an image.
2. display it.
3. save it in some file.

Preferably:

1. portable.
2. with no external dependencies.

If not portable, should work on Windows. 
If with external dependencies, something freely distributable and easy to bundle (like a dll/so file).

If the image is tuple class `image`, then (2) (displaying) is covered by `ui` and images.viewer` vocabs.

But I can't find a straightforward way to create and draw to an `image`, or output it in a raster format.

I don't care about:

- having to draw pixel by pixel, as for the time being it would just be drawing simple straight lines.
- bad performance. (Completely Ridiculously Awful Performance might be an issue, though ;)

What is the easiest way to do this in Factor?

Comment: Have you looked into the `images.bitmap` vocabulary?

Comment: I remember when I tried to work with `images.png` a week or two ago -- just figuring out how to make a `loading-png` object from an io stream was confusing.

Comment: @cat I did, but didn't get anywhere, I'll have a closer look. Can you point me in some direction? And yeah, confused is what I am right now!

Comment: @cat  Also, If you have time you could document your streaming adventure somewhere? maybe a Q-A here? Would be nice! :D

Comment: I would be happy to do that, since I'm kinda stumped with [socket programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511260/how-do-i-write-to-a-duplex-stream) right now (maybe you can help with that?) :P

Comment: The first and third points are simple enough that I can cook up an answer. I am not, however, at all experienced with UI development in Factor and so just looking at [the `ui.images` documentation](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/vocab-ui.images.html) is making me sigh. If you've already got a UI `world` up and running, it will probably be no problem to just call `draw-image`.

Comment: @cat Sure, post it! I'm not interested in a full fledged  UI right now. That can come later, as long as I can do it in the listener :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37623559/ https://github.com/exercism/xfactor http://exercism.io/languages/factor :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order:

1. **Programmatically draw an image**.

We're talking about [bitmaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap), which means unfortunately you'll need to work with each byte individually, unless you'd rather work with the even-less-documented [`svg` vocabulary](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/vocab-svg.html), which seems under-featured.

The good news is that Factor has lots of higher-order functions for working with arrays. Additionally, the promising-sounding [`images.processing`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/vocab-images.processing.html) vocab doesn't have very many words for this sort of thing.

What you'll actually want to do (as far as I can tell) is make a valid [file header](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-file-header%2Cimages.bitmap.html), then write the image data and header to a `.bmp` file.

2. **Display it**.

Less easy. It seems like [`ui.images`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-draw-image%2Cui.images.html) will take an `image-name` (whatever that is -- something that implements `path>>`, so maybe it's expecting a stream or file object?) and apparently `display` it in the current UI `world`, which is likely simpler if you have a UI already.

Just look at `world`'s constructor:

```
TUPLE: world < track
    active? focused? grab-input? fullscreen? saved-position
    layers title status status-owner text-handle handle images
    window-loc pixel-format-attributes background-color promise
    window-controls window-resources ;
```

Damn, son.

3. **Save it in some file**.

This one I can actually give an implementation for since it's pretty simple once you get the hang of it.

You've got an image in a folder, and we're going to load it into the listener. (Again, displaying it is a whole 'nother story).

```
USING: images.bitmap io.encodings.binary io.files ;

: bmp-open ( path -- stream ) binary <file-reader> load-bitmap ;
```

`<file-reader>` needs a `path` and an `encoding` (from `io.encodings`), and leaves an `io.stream` on the stack, which is what `load-png`, `load-bitmap` etc are looking for.

That will give us a `loading-bmp`, which is more useful than it sounds.

```
T{ loading-bitmap
    { file-header
        T{ file-header
            { size 12726 }
            { offset 54 }
            { header-length 40 }
        }
    }
    { header
        T{ v3-header
            { width 64 }
            { height 66 }
            { planes 1 }
            { bit-count 24 }
            { image-size 12672 }
        }
    }
    { color-index
        B{
            255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
            255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
            255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
            255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
            255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
            255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
            255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
            255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 ~12573 more~
        }
    }
}
```

The data you're looking for is obviously in `color-index>>`.

```
dup color-index>>

--- Data stack:
T{ loading-bitmap f ~file-header~ ~v3-header~ f ~byte-array~ f }
B{ 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255...
```

You can mess with that array however you like, and then just do `>>color-index` (or mess with `loading-bitmap`'s constructor), and write those bytes to a file.

```
TUPLE: loading-bitmap
    file-header header color-palette color-index bitfields ;
```

Something like `loading-bitmap>bytes` or `bitmap>bytes` should help you there.

---

When I was writing this answer last night, I totally didn't think to look on [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Factor) for bitmap-related things.

- [A UI displaying colour bars](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Colour_bars/Display#Factor), like:

[image]

- Bézier curves, of varying, um, variances:

  - [Quadratic](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/B%C3%A9zier_curves/Quadratic#Factor), and
  - [Cubic](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/B%C3%A9zier_curves/Cubic#Factor)
- [Storing bitmaps](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Basic_bitmap_storage#Factor)
- [Bresenham's Line Algorithm](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#Factor)
- [Bitmap operations in general](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap#Factor)
- [Image noise](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Image_noise#Factor)
- and [more](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Factor) :D

Comment: Wow! Thanks, that's very very helpful :D I wish I could stay playing with this all night...

Comment: @fedes. I've added some more information to my answer :D

Comment: ouo Awww, wish I could +1 lots of times!

Comment: @fedes. [Halp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512483/how-can-i-get-a-connected-clients-ip-address) :P

Comment: @fedes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951947/cleave-a-run-time-computed-value