# How do I write to a duplex stream?

Tags: sockets, stream, factor-lang

Suppose I have a Super Simple Socket Server that accepts connections on a port at `localhost`:

```
: server-new ( port -- stream ) f swap <inet4> utf8 <server> accept drop ;
```

And I can use it like:

```
IN: scratchpad 1204 server-new
```

Which waits for a connection. In a terminal:

```
$ curl localhost:1204
_
```

Which then waits for the server to reply. `server-new` leaves a `duplex-stream` on the stack.

```
T{ duplex-stream
    { in
        T{ decoder
            { stream
                T{ input-port
                    { handle T{ fd { fd 36 } } }
                    { buffer
                        T{ buffer
                            { size 65536 }
                            { ptr ALIEN: 1a44530 }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            { code utf8 }
        }
    }
    { out
        T{ encoder
            { stream
                T{ output-port
                    { handle T{ fd { fd 36 } } }
                    { buffer
                        T{ buffer
                            { size 65536 }
                            { ptr ALIEN: 1d42b30 }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            { code utf8 }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a string to the client. How do I do this?

It seems like `with-stream` or something would be the answer, but that just consumes the stream object and nothing gets written to my `curl` client.

Comment: `[ "hello from Factor" print flush ] with-stream*` works for me!

Comment: @fedes. Holy cats, you're a genius, thank you! make that an answer :D

Comment: Didn't look enough for an answer ;) And I don't know much about streams, let's see if someone can give some substance!

Comment: Sh*t, I can't speak English when I drink! :/ My prev comment actually meant "It didn't seem enough to be an answer". :P

Comment: @fedes. I assure you, any (native?) speaker knew what you meant :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably missing a flush somewhere:

```
[ "hello from Factor" print flush ] with-stream
```

Also notice that `with-stream` will close the stream when the quotation finishes. If you want to leave it open, use `with-stream*` instead.