# How can I get a connected client's IP address?

Tags: sockets, stream, server, factor-lang

If I have a Super Simple Threaded TCP Server like:

```
USING: accessors io io.encodings.utf8 io.servers 
    io.sockets kernel prettyprint threads ;

: handle-client ( -- )
   remote-address . ;

: <my-server> ( -- threaded-server )
    utf8 <threaded-server>
        "server" >>name
        1234 >>insecure
        [ handle-client ] >>handler ;

: start-my-server ( -- )
    <my-server> [ start-server ] in-thread start-server drop ;
```

This will just print the text `remote-address` to the client, which is *very* helpful. That's because `remote-address` is a symbol... where's its value?
The [documentation](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-remote-address%2Cio.sockets.html) for `remote-address` says:

> Variable holding the address specifier of the current client connection.

And the docs on `<threaded-server>` say:

> The handler slot of a threaded server instance should be set to a
>   quotation which handles client connections. Client handlers are run in
>   their own thread, with the following variables rebound:
>
> • input-stream
>   • output-stream
>   • local-address
>   • **remote-address**
>   • threaded-server

Great! That means I can get at a client's IP.

Then it links to [Address specifiers](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-network-addressing.html), which seems to be related, but doesn't clearly explain how to get data from `remote-address`.

How can I get a client's IP address?

Comment: If it's a symbol bound to a value (IOW a variable :P), shouldn't you `get` it? What does that give you?

Comment: @fedes. ....... *facepalm* Oh, *that's* what that's for. Make that an answer :P

Comment: I honestly never actually bothered to figure out what `get` was for, now I see.

Comment: Hehe. You did all the work, it'll be a better answer if you post it!

Comment: @fedes. I still blame the documentation for being comprehensive yet *utterly* unhelpful.

Comment: Yeah, I got lost and confused so many times in the docs! Maybe someday it will appeal to the masses, get a really nice doc, and we will have to look for another under-documented unknown language to play with :P

Comment: @fedes. It just occurred to me I used `get` three times in the question's body, and that turned out to be the blatantly obvious answer. Everyone starts somewhere...

Comment: haha, well, I should tell you how I spent an hour+ and almost post a question because I couldn't see where I missed a space ; P Obvious things are sometimes the harder to see, amiright?

Comment: @fedes. Of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@fede s.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512483/how-can-i-get-a-connected-clients-ip-address?noredirect=1#comment60651331_36512483) nailed it in the comments: [`get`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-get,namespaces.html) will take a `variable` and `get` its value.

So my code from the question becomes:

```
: handle-client ( -- )
   remote-address get host>> print flush ;

: <my-server> ( -- threaded-server )
    utf8 <threaded-server>
        "server" >>name
        1234 >>insecure
        [ handle-client ] >>handler ;

: start-my-server ( -- )
    <my-server> [ start-server ] in-thread start-server drop ;
```

Comment: You should accept this answer, It's the best one so far!

Comment: @fedes. xD SE always tells me "you can accept this answer in 24 hours" and then I go away and *completely* forget I *can* accept my own answer *after* 24 hours. Thank you for reminding me :P