# Shadowing a vocabulary name from the standard library

Tags: factor-lang

For reasons that don't really matter, I *need* to have a vocabulary named `hello-world` and I *need* to be able to run its tests, and I *need* it to shadow the `hello-world` from Factor's standard library.

I have not been able to do this successfully (I tried reversing `vocab-roots` but it did not make a difference). Is it possible?

Comment: I just tried reversing and it worked... `vocab-roots get reverse vocab-roots set USE: hello-world` -> Loading resource:work/hello-world/hello-world.factor. You sure?

Comment: @fedes. Aha. I didn't realise it mattered the `hello-world` in the question is *not* in the Factor source tree, which does change the outcome.

Comment: Can you `"path-that-contains-your-vocab" add-vocab-root`? After that reversing vocab-roots and USE: worked too.

Comment: @fedes. `USE:` doesn't cut it, I have to `run-file` but that's what I wanna do anyways. `add-vocab-root` after reversing `vocab-roots` is the kicker, thank you!